# How to create a DOM Element and use it in real time using Meteor and Templates

Tags: templates, dom, meteor, real-time

everybody.

I am using Meteor in a personal project and I could not do something very important to this project: I need to create some parts of the DOM in runtime and then populate them still in runtime, but using the Tamplates method I could not do this work. Maybe I am doing something wrong. Please, take a look in this example and say what's wrong or if there is a better way to do it.

Consider this example situation:

```
<template name = "exampleTemplate">
    <div class="divToPopulate">
        {{#each topModels}}
            <div id="{{_id}}"></div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

Then, in *client.js* I provide the data for *topModels* helper:

```
Template.exampleTemplate.topModels = function() {
    return ExampleModel.find({},{limit:9});
}
```

When the Template is ready, I try to use those DOM elements in a javascript function called *drawGraph(var domElementId)* that is a Raphael.js function which draws a graph inside the DIV:

```
Template.exampleTemplate.rendered = function() {
    var models = ExampleModel.find({},{limit:9});
    models.forEach(function(model){
        drawGraph(model._id);
    });
}
```

But when I run this I get an error saying that the DOM element doesn't exist. So I was wondering if there is a better way to append an DOM element and populate it on the fly.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: 1. Do you have to give an id name or class name in the Raphael code? In the template you are specifying the class instead of id. 2. Is there a typo in your original code? You want model._id not mode._id.

Comment: Hi, there. Yes, that's a typo, sorry (I just fixed it). And yes too: the Raphael code ask for a id, but in this hypothetical situation actually it doesn't matter if its an id or class because the problem is not with Raphael function, it's with the DOM element. But I'll change that for an ID too. Thanks for replay. :)

Comment: Your Meteor code seems correct and it's the usual way to accomplish this task, have you checked in the browser debugger that 9 DIVs are correctly appended to the DOM ? Could you show the code of drawGraph and especially how you feed Raphael with the div id ?

Comment: The code seems correct, the error is probably somewhere in the `drawGraph` method.

Comment: A long shot, but since you don't specify how to sort the documents, the two calls `ExampleModel.find({},{limit:9})` maybe result in different documents? Or maybe some new documents been inserted between the two calls (if that's possible)?

Comment: Thanks, guys. It seems to be my misunderstand. I was looking at the terminal output and I got this error message: `Exception from Deps afterFlush function: TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined` then I considered to be a DOM Element missing error. But it turns out not. I inspected the DOM and I saw that all elements were created correctly (sorry, I forgot to do that before). So, it seems to be an error inside _drawGraph_. Thanks everybody for the help, but I think that this question doesn't make sense anymore. Thanks again.

Comment: (PS: Should I delete this Question or leave it for future reference?).

Comment: @jhow You can post your own solution as an answer, that's probably the best thing if somebody else finds a similar issue in the future.